# Dimension Error when feeding 3d tensor into CNN and keras network

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

My Xtrain is a RGB image of dimension (numofsamples,height,width,channel).
Where numofsamples = 1047, height = 128, width = 128, channels = 3.

This is done by running the codes below:

```
for img_filename in train_files:
    img = image.load_img(os.path.join(rootdir,'train_image/train_image',img_filename), target_size=(128,128,1))
    img = image.img_to_array(img)
    img = img/255
    train_image.append(img)
X_train = np.array(train_image)
```

Im trying to run a CNN+LSTM model on the data with image augmentation. But I keep getting different dimensions error.

1. If I were to run this code:

```
batch_size = 64
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='relu',input_shape = (128,128,3))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(LSTM(512, return_sequences=False, dropout=0.1))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='Adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit_generator(train_generator.flow(Xtrain,ytrain,batch_size=batch_size),
                        #steps_per_epoch = Xtrain.shape[0] // batch_size,
                        epochs = 50,
                        verbose = True,
                        validation_data= (Xval,yval),
                        callbacks = [reduce_lr,es,ModelCheckpoint('cnnlstm'+'_weights.hdf5', monitor='val_accuracy', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')]
                       )
```

My error encountered is:

> InvalidArgumentError: input must be 4-dimensional[8192,128,3] [Op:Conv2D]

If I were to reshape it to (1047, 128, 128, 3, 1), I will get a numpy error.

```
Xtrain_reshape = np.expand_dims(Xtrain, -1)
Xval_reshape = np.expand_dims(Xval, -1)

model = Sequential()
# define CNN model
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='relu',input_shape = (128,128,3))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
# define LSTM model
model.add(LSTM(512, return_sequences=False, dropout=0.1))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='Adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit_generator(train_generator.flow(Xtrain_reshape,ytrain,batch_size=batch_size),
                        #steps_per_epoch = Xtrain.shape[0] // batch_size,
                        epochs = 50,
                        verbose = True,
                        validation_data= (Xval_reshape,yval),
                        callbacks = [reduce_lr,es,ModelCheckpoint('cnnlstm'+'_weights.hdf5', monitor='val_accuracy', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')]
                       )
```

My error here is

> ValueError: ('Input data in `NumpyArrayIterator` should have rank 4. You passed an array with shape', (1047, 128, 128, 3, 1))

Can you let me know how to reshape it, so I can go through CNN and LSTM?

Comment: give code of where you are preparing your data. Your original error says your input data shape is `(8192,128,3)`

Comment: @mb0850 My batch size is 64. so i guess its batch size*image height =  64*128

Comment: That shouldn't be the case, if your batch size is 64 then the input shape should be `(64, 128, 128, 3)`. You need to give the code you are using the generate your training/testing data so that we can understand where the issue is.

Comment: I load it from my directory and only ran the codes above to generate the train data

Comment: There still seems to be a disconnect in the code you provided, between `model.fit_generator(train_generator.flow(Xtrain,ytrain,batch_size=batch_size)` and the `X_train` that you are creating.